# 'int' object is not iterable in class __init__ definition

Tags: python, class, pygame

```
class MenuItem():
def __init__(self, width, height, (posX, posY)=(0,0)):
    #self.label = self.render(self.text, 1, self.font_color)
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.posX = posX
    self.posY = posY
    self.position = posX, posY

def set_position(self, x, y):
    self.position = (x, y)
    self.posX = x
    self.posY = y

def is_mouse_selection(self, (posx, posy)):
    if (posx >= self.posX and posx <= self.posX + self.width) and (posy >= self.posY and posy <= self.posY + self.height):
        return True
    return False

def draw(self):
    raise MissingFunction("Child of MenuItem class has no draw function")    

class RadioButton(MenuItem):
def __init__(width, (posX, posY) = (0, 0)):
    super(RadioButton, self).__init__(width, width, (posX, posY))
    self.active = False

def draw(screen):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen. GREY, pygame.Rect(posX, posY, self.width, self.height))
    if self.active:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, (posX + (self.width / 2), posY + (self.height / 2)), self.width)
    else:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, (posX + (self.width / 2), posY + (self.height / 2)), self.width, 1)

class RadioFrame(MenuItem):
def __init__(numButtons, buttonWidth, (posX, posY)=(0, 0)):
    super(RadioFrame, self).__init__(numButtons * buttonWidth, width)
    self.set_position(posX, posY)
    self.numButtons = numButtons
    self.buttons = []
    self.activeButton = None
    curX = self.posX
    for i in enumerate(self.numButtons):
        self.buttons.append(RadioButton(buttonWidth, (curX, self.posY)))
        curX += buttonWidth
```

I'm trying to create a child of my MenuItem class, RadioFrame, which contains a list of RadioButton objects. I already have other successfully running children that are initialized in a similar way.

I'm getting the error that int object isn't iterable, I know that, but I'm struggling to see where I'm making that error. It's being triggered:
`line 44, in __init__
    def __init__(numButtons, buttonWidth, (posX, posY)=(0, 0)):`

For some more context here is where I am creating new instances of the class:
    numRadios = 2 # 2 Frames
        index = 0

```
    # First Num Players
    ## PosX = middle of screen width - middle of (numButtons * buttonWidth) [aka RadioFrame width]
    ## PosY = middle of screen height - middle of (buttonWidth) [aka RadioFrame height]
    playerRadio = RadioFrame(3, 50)
    posx = (self.scr_width / 2) - ((50 * 3) / 2)
    posy = (self.scr_height / 2) - (50 / 2) + ((index * 2) + index * 50) # Copied from text button position, index starts at zero
    playerRadio.set_position(posx, posy)
    self.items.append(playerRadio)
    index += 1
```

Full Trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
>  File "./main.py", line 61, in <module>
>
>    2: PreGameMenu(screen, clock, preGameFuncs.keys(), preGameFuncs),
>
>  File "/home/rhartman/Documents/pitch/menus.py", line 113, in __init__
>
>    playerRadio = RadioFrame(3, 50)
>
>  File "/home/rhartman/Documents/pitch/menus.py", line 44, in __init__
>
>    def __init__(numButtons, buttonWidth, (posX, posY)=(0, 0)):
> ```
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Why not `posX=0, posY=0`?

Comment: Post the full ErrorTrace, but I believe this is the offending portion: ` for i in enumerate(self.numButtons):` Isn't `self.numButtons` and `int`? Also, your `__init__` method is missing a `self` parameter.

Comment: @jonrsharpe where?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga self.numButtons is an int, I originally had `for i in range(0, numButtons)` but changed it while trying to debug this, ironically I may have stepped backwards. Adding self to the __init__ function did change the error though. `super(RadioFrame, self).__init__(numButtons * buttonWidth, width)
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
`

Comment: In the definition of the method. If you have code to add please do so with an [edit], as it's hard to read in comments.

Comment: Ah and that type not classobj error is because my `MenuItem` base class wasn't inheriting from `object`

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is valid python 2 syntax, you're expected to pass a tuple, and it will be unpacked as those pseudo-parameters

Comment: @RyHartAttack the `__init__` of RadioFrame's first parameter should be `self`, not `numButtons`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to iterate an integer.

```
class RadioFrame(MenuItem):
    def __init__(numButtons, buttonWidth, (posX, posY)=(0, 0)):
        super(RadioFrame, self).__init__(numButtons * buttonWidth, width)
        self.set_position(posX, posY)
        self.numButtons = numButtons
        self.buttons = []
        self.activeButton = None
        curX = self.posX
        for i in enumerate(self.numButtons):
            self.buttons.append(RadioButton(buttonWidth, (curX, self.posY)))
            curX += buttonWidth

playerRadio = RadioFrame(3, 50)
```

According to your code `self.numButtons` is an integer 3. Then you're trying to iterate through it in this line `for i in enumerate(self.numButtons):`. It maybe should be `for i in xrange(self.numButtons):`.